# How does one have Greasemonkey run before *anything* else in the page?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Is it possible to have Greasemonkey scripts run before *anything* else on the page?

I'm aware of `@run-at document-start`, but this appears to run immediately after the `<HTML>` tag. Normally this isn't a problem, but if the page is misformatted as in the example below, there doesn't seem to be anything I can do.

I'd appreciate any suggestions or ideas. 
Thanks!

```
<script>alert('This is an annoying message.');</script>
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
    <HTML>
        <HEAD>
...etc...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible, because HTML requres that scripts are executed *during* parsing or not at all, e.g. this is allowed:

```
<script> document.write('<!'+'--'); </script>
```

If browser goes past this script without executing it, it will see completely different document, therefore you can't analyze DOM of HTML document before scripts run.

Opera solves this problem in [UserJS](http://www.opera.com/browser/tutorials/userjs/specs/) by firing `BeforeScript` events, allowing UserJS to change/remove scripts at the very last moment.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, `@run-at document-start` **does** pretty much run the GM script before anything from the page.

In your case, the following code will work in conjunction with `@run-at document-start`:

```
_oldAlert           = alert;
unsafeWindow.alert  = function () {};

/*-- Optionally, wait for the DOM, then set an onload handler to restore
    alert().
*/
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried:

```
(function() {
    var yourFunction = function() 
    {
       // ...
    }
    window.addEventListener("load", yourFunction, false);
})();
```

Comment: Good thought. But, the listener still seems to start only after the <html> tag. Thanks though.

Comment: greasemonkey executes the userscript on the domready event, the load event is fired at the later point after all the resources have been loaded