# Bypass undefined variable

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

This site I am trying to access, has

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
function setCanvasSize()
{
  FB.Canvas.setAutoResize(false);
  FB.Canvas.setSize({ "width": 760, "height": 730 });
}
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  setCanvasSize();
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  setCanvasSize();
});
```

on the homepage, however FB is undefined because I have Facebook blocked in my hosts file.

Whenever I try to access it, it spits the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined` and I see a blank page.

I tried to set `var FB = 0;` with a greasemonkey script for the page, however it didn't work. Anyone know how I can get around this? Is there anyway to remove this javascript from the page with greasemonkey?

Comment: If anybody hosted the referenced js file on CDN,then link to it.like google did for jquery.

Answer (score 1):

I see no choice but to "overwrite" this object when it does not exist.

Put this code in the very end of your page:

```
if (typeof FB == "undefined" || !FB) {
    FB = { 
        Canvas: {
            setAutoResize: function() {}, 
            setSize: function() {}
        }
    };
}
```

This way the code in `$(document).ready()` will use this dummy object and won't crash.

Comment: Hi, I can't modify the javascript, It's not my page just a site I'm visting

Comment: @joerosa sorry not familiar with greasemonkey I assumed you have website using that code as external resource.

Comment: This still won't work, at least not by itself - though the mock objects will be good to use.  Please refer to my answer for as to why.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.setCanvasSize = '';
function setCanvasSize()
{
      try {
          FB.Canvas.setAutoResize(false);
          FB.Canvas.setSize({ "width": 760, "height": 730 });
          }
          catch (e) {}
}
```

Try this

Comment: The OP can't modify this JS, so this isn't an option.

Comment: Hi, I tried I get the same error "Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined"

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 issues here.

First, setting `FB = 0` would prevent an error on accessing `FB.Canvas`, but any accessors to `FB.Canvas` - such as `FB.Canvas.setAutoResize` will still throw the error.

Second, all of this probably happens before your GreaseMonkey script executes.

---

**Edit:**

You need to use `@run_at document_start`.  See http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40run-at and https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/1103 for details.  Available as of GreaseMonkey 0.9.8+.  Then, use the mock objects provided by Shadow Wizard in his answer.

Also make sure that you're properly interfacing with the content Window, not the GreaseMonkey scope.  This works, but per the embedded and below comments - this needs some security work!

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Mock Facebook
// @namespace      ...
// @include        ...
// @run-at         document-start
// ==/UserScript==

// DO NOT DO THIS - EXAMPLE ONLY - SEE http://wiki.greasespot.net/UnsafeWindow

unsafeWindow.FB = {
    Canvas: {
        setAutoResize: function(){},
        setSize: function(){}
    }
};
```

This needs some further work to get around using the unsafe [`unsafeWindow`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/UnsafeWindow), but this is a working example that can hopefully be properly extended upon by yourself or someone else.  (I tried both http://wiki.greasespot.net/Content_Script_Injection and http://wiki.greasespot.net/Content_Script_Injection, but neither of these worked - possibly again due to timing issues.  I may also revisit this later as well.)  Also, be sure to fill-in an appropriate `@namespace` and `@include`.

There is no need to check for an existing `FB` variable first, as there is really no way it can otherwise exist at this point - so there is no concern of overwriting something.

---

Otherwise, the only work-around I can immediately think of is a Firefox extension that provides a mock `FB` object in the page scope before pages even load.

Comment: So, there's no way to get around this?

Comment: @joerosa - Not according to this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/708136/how-does-one-have-greasemonkey-run-before-anything-else-in-the-page

Comment: @joerosa - See my updated answer.  I've not used this before, but `@run_at document_start` may work for you (after resolving the other issues that I noted).

Comment: I used @run_at document_start, however still getting the error with Shadow Wizards answer. I guess I can just unblock Facebook from my hosts, I didn't realize it would be this complicated. (Reason for blocking is I prefer not to have my every move tracked by them with their like buttons and all) Thanks for taking the time to try and help me!

Comment: @joerosa - would you mind sharing the URL for the site you're trying this with?  Now I'm curious to get this resolved.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use both `@run-at document-start` and `unsafeWindow` like so:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name    _Ensure that setCanvasSize or FB is defined
// @include YOUR_SITE/YOUR_PATH
// @run-at  document-start
// ==/UserScript==

unsafeWindow.FB = { 
    Canvas: {
        setSize:        function () {},
        setAutoResize:  function () {} 
    }
};
```

Beware that the GM script will start running before the DOM is available, so attempts at DOM manipulation or even `alert()` or `console.log()` can cause the script to silently fail.

Just setting JS objects, like the script I've given, is fine, though.